# Local stateless EJB injection within singleton startup EJB

Tags: singleton, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.1, stateless

is this possible somehow? Following scenario:

- statelesse local EJB with name A
- singleton startup EJB with name B
- B contains a reference to A

I tried but my application server (WAS) fails on application startup with the error that A was not found. The console log also makes clear that A was not started at the moment the B is loaded but some other stateless EJBs are started before B. Making A also a singleton EJB and letting B depond on A via annotation @DependsOn({"A"}) produced an error, too, stating that dependent bean A was not found. Using A in a web module works fine.

Any ideas what' I do wrong? Thx for any help!
Steffen Harbich

Comment: In GlassFish I have the same error. It disappears if you remove the local interface from A. Why do you need the local interface? It seems that shouldn't be necessary with EJB 3.1

Comment: This should work.  Is A in the same module/application as B or separate?  If separate, is the module of A configured to start before the module of B (initialize-in-order in application.xml, or using module starting weights in the admin console)?

Comment: Ok, i'll try to remove local interface.

Comment: A is in another ejb module than B but within same application. Any ideas, how to set starting weights in Websphere?

Comment: N1! The startup order did it. If you post this as answer then I can mark it as answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any chance to specify module startup weight / order via ejb-jar.xml or annotation, @bkail?

Comment: The only options are initialize-in-order in application.xml or via the admin console.  Arguably the product could automatically assign weights based on DependsOn, but it does not do that as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is in a different module/application as B, then you need to ensure that the module of A is configured to start before the module of B.  You can either use initialize-in-order in application.xml, or use module starting weights in the admin console.